# Why I can't pip install nltk on mac os?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip

I'm using mac os mojave, install python 2.7 and install pip using `python get-pip.py`, I already try those command to install pip :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install nltk
```

and try

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade nltk
```

But also result to same error like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsiGA.png)

Or here in text:

> error in nltk setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or
>   list of strings containing valid project/version requirement
>   specifiers; Expected version spec in singledispatch; python_version <
>   "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"

Is it because my python version (2.7) ? But in pip ntlk page it says also support 2.7

**update:**

`pip install nltk` success after running :

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip --user
```

Comment: Note one of your command has `ntlk` instead of `nltk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with upgrading installation tools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```