# import Colab Python Error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

When I try to install Colab (via. pip), I get the following error:

```
`(.venv) PS F:\PythonProject\Übeersetzung_KI> pip install colab
Collecting colab
  Using cached colab-1.13.5.tar.gz (567 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      error in colab setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz>=2011n
              ~~~~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.`
```

I tried to reinstall Jupyter and Pycharm, but the error persists.

**EDIT: I fixed the problem by install "Desktop development with C++" workload in Visual Studio.**

Comment: The pytz>=2011n seems to be the problematic part. There may be a typo or formatting error in the package's dependency specification `2011n` ??

Comment: @user70 do you know how to fix ist?

Comment: unfortunatelly not, I'm not familiar with colab environment :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77704895/7976758 Are you sure you want to install https://pypi.org/project/colab/ and not https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/ ? Are you sure you want to install google-colab from PyPI and not from GitHub? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77829634/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669921/7976758 For the generic error "*error in setup command: install_requires must be a string or list of strings*" the solution is `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` . See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error+in+setup+command%3A+install_requires+must+be+a+string+or+list+of+strings

Comment: you don't install colab. it is run in the browser.

Comment: @phd I tried to install google-colab but there was following a bigger error (https://pastes.dev/HzNL5IO33z).

Also tried github with github (https://pastes.dev/vRVEbtlQO6)

Comment: I fix it by install "Desktop development with C++" workload in Visual Studio.
But now this error cames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78225135/failed-building-wheel-for-pyzmq-durring-the-installation-of-colab-with-github