# Failed building wheel for pyzmq durring the installation of colab (with github)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyzmq

I encountered an error during the installation of Google Colab using GitHub.

The error message states:

```
 Building editable for google.colab (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for google.colab: filename=google_colab-1.0.0-0.editable-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=7839 sha256=310e1f601bb7341b3b3b56aee60e244d5dfa2793846645d33f0b388595742df6
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\zGamerZz - Main\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-vxb3m90z\wheels\66\56\3d\e8c1ef93e93b0fde766fa8ae21d02f7c24dec6c19a5c1bfbbc
  Building wheel for pyzmq (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyzmq (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [431 lines of output]
```

at the end:

```
  error: command 'F:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq
Successfully built google.colab
Failed to build pyzmq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

While Google Colab built successfully, the installation failed due to an issue building pyzmq.

I then attempted to install pyzmq manually using pip.

Comment: Welcome! Please post your complete error message with the code that you tried.

Comment: Hi @TalhaTayyab,
yes, sorry i forgot one part. I edited the post :)